# Using Row(Indirect(string)) not working

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have been trying to use `=row(indirect("0-5000"))` to work like I have read on all literature I could find and yet I keep getting the #REF error, which occurs when it processes the indirect(string) part of the formula. Is there a setting somewhere that is making my function to act improperly?
[image]

I am trying to produce an array of numbers inside a formula at time of calcution (so no stored array), based on a range of two numbers from 2 cells like the example 1/4 of the way down on https://exceljet.net/formula/create-array-of-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=row(indirect("1:5000"))
```

There is no row 0 and a colon is used to delimit the upper and lower limits of a range.

[image]

[image]